# Check what part of an IF statement is false/true when using logical operators

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

Is there a way to check which part of an if statment is flase/true?

For example, I've got two variable $a and $b. If any of them is empty I want to stop my function, but i want also to echo a specific message for each one. My code is:

```
if(empty($a) || empty($b)){
  if(empty($a)){echo('$a is empty');}
  if(empty($b)){echo ('$b is empty');}
  return;
}
```

Actually I've got many more variables and this is just a semplification. I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the double if check and to clean the code.
Thank you

Comment: You _could_ use variable variables … Put the _names_ of your variables into an array, then loop over them, and check each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way. In the case you describe PHP will not evaluate all the content of the parentheses.

In case empty($a) is true, php will not evaluate empty($b). Because the OR will be true anyway.

You can do the following test:

```
$a = 1; $b = 0;
if($a || $c) print "2";
```

This should be show `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: c..` But instead it print 2

The best is to evaluate separately

```
try{
    if(empty($a)) throw new \Exception('$a is empty');
    if(empty($b)) throw new \Exception('$b is empty');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print($e->getMessage());
}
```